# Adding 4 finger gesture in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, gestures, touchegg

I have installed `touchegg` and added the following lines in `.xprofile`

```
synclient TapButton2=0
synclient ClickFinger2=0
synclient TapButton3=0
synclient ClickFinger3=0
synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=0
synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=0
touchegg &
```

But now I want to add four finger gesture with which we can move to different windows(like in MacOs). How is that possible?